# Android, added adaptive icons, now I get schema error on upload

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I added adaptive icons to my application, it compiles and builds just fine, but when trying to upload to the play store, I get the following error:

`You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which specifies an actions schema document in its manifest, but the actions schema document was given at an invalid location: 'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'. Actions schema documents must be located under res/xml and specified as a resource file beginning with @xml/.`

Has anybody seen this before? I followed all the steps to create the adaptive icons.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `manifest` file had an error, I had:

```
<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.actions"
       android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

I just remove it, and play store accepted the apk.